# Apple Music genre selection screen

Tags: ios, swift, uikit-dynamics

Does anybody have an idea how the genre selection bubbles in Apple music were made? The movement seems to be done with UiKit Dynamics. I definitely see collision behaviors but can't seem to reproduce the fluidity of the drag movement and the gravity towards the center of the view. I tried using `UIPushBehavior` and `UiSnapBehavior`, but no luck.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

I don't think that it was done with UIKit Dynamics, I think they was using SpriteKit.
I created a component that's can simulate similar physics

https://github.com/ProudOfZiggy/SIFloatingCollection_Swift

Answer (score 5):

It is possible with UIKitDynamics as well, but can be done with SpriteKit as well which makes it much easier to implement, I have written a small component which give similar kind of effect in Objecti-C using SpriteKit. You can find it [here](https://github.com/CoderXpert/AnimatedMenuPool), Its not exactly the same but its near and you can take same approach to create your own or polish it as well.

Answer (score 1):

i have developed it using box2d and libGdx on android,, so using libGdx u can use my code logic for iOS also...
have a look at my project, hope it helps,
https://github.com/mohitKejriwal/Bubble-UI-Android